# ERROR: Primary output targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86' (BUT IT IS!)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I know there are 100s of posts like this, **but I have set my solution and all of my projects to x64**. Whenever I try to build my Setup Project, I get a few errors about dlls that are along the lines of:
' xxxx is targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with project's target platform 'x86''

See the screenshots below.

I can batch build just fine, but when I try to build the Setup Project I get those errors. I've also tried restarting VS and I still get those errors.

[image]

Here are some screenshots of my Build. . The first project is the main WPF solution. The second project is a Models class (Class Library), the 3rd is the Installer (Setup Project) and the 4th is a Services Class (Class Library)

[image]

Here is the Configuration Manager:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to generate an MSI installer through this program?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT yes